# Microsoft exchange online powershell connection Authentication issue

Tags: azure-powershell, exchange-online

I am tryig to connect Exchange Online via Powershell using Regsitered App Id .

getting Unauthorized/InSufficient Scope while trying to connect .

I have to user AccessToken as dont have access to admin credentails . My Registered app given all permissions mentioned 'Exchange.ManageAsApp'

[image]

```
$tenantId = <tenantId>
$clientId = <appId>
$clientSecret = <client secret>

$tokenRequestUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"

$body = @{
    "grant_type" = "client_credentials"
    "client_id" = $clientId
    "client_secret" = $clientSecret
    "scope"="Exchange.Manage"
    "resource" = "https://outlook.office.com" # Update with the specific resource URL if needed
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenRequestUrl -Method Post -Body $body

$accessToken = $response.access_token

Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId <appId> -AccessToken $accessToken -Organization "*****.onmicrosoft.com"
```

App given with permissions

gettign below error :

OperationStopped: The role assigned to application 35ec1526-639c-4230-a4cb-abfab0126122 isn't supported in this scenario. Please check online documentation for
assigning correct Directory Roles to Azure AD Application for EXO App-Only Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect Exchange Online via PowerShell using Azure AD application grant **`Exchange.ManageAsApp` Application API permission**:

[image]

Now when I executed the script, I got the **same error** like below:

```
$tenantId = <tenantId>
$clientId = <appId>
$clientSecret = <client secret>

$tokenRequestUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"

$body = @{
    "grant_type" = "client_credentials"
    "client_id" = $clientId
    "client_secret" = $clientSecret
    "scope"="Exchange.Manage"
    "resource" = "https://outlook.office.com" # Update with the specific resource URL if needed
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenRequestUrl -Method Post -Body $body

$accessToken = $response.access_token

Connect-ExchangeOnline -AppId <appId> -AccessToken $accessToken -Organization "*****.onmicrosoft.com"
```

[image]

> The role assigned to application xxx isn't supported in this scenario. Please check online documentation for assigning correct Directory Roles to Azure AD Application for EXO App-Only Authentication

The error usually occurs if the Azure AD application doesn't have required roles to perform the action.

**To resolve the error,** make sure to assign any one of the Microsoft Entra roles to the SPN/application. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#assign-microsoft-entra-roles-to-the-application)

*I assigned Active assignment **Exchange Administrator role** for the application*:

[image]

[image]

**After assigning the role, I am able to `Connect-ExchangeOnline` successfully:**

[image]

Comment: Here I am not able to select Registered app to assign Role. Its only listing users and Groups

Comment: Did you search with app name?

Comment: Yes .. I am able to searched by name and added. and Successfully Connected . Is there any Graph API to assign role to App ?

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/manage-roles-portal

Comment: am trying to register for Enterprise App from Web Application via MSAL. When I tried to add "https://outlook.office.com/Exchange.Manage" Scope it throwing error. @Rukmini